# Unable to call interface methods through proxy object

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
public class proxy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s ="Happy";
        InvocationHandler handler = new Handler(s);
        Class[] interfaces = s.getClass().getInterfaces();
        Object myproxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(null,interfaces,handler);
        System.out.println(myproxy.compareTo("hoppu"));
    }
}

class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
    public Handler(Object t) {
        target = t;
    }
    public Object invoke(Object proxy,Method m,Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(m.getName());
        return m.invoke(target,args);
    }
    private Object target;
}
```

Proxy object can call the interfaces as it implements them.I am getting this error when i am compiling this code.

```
proxy.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method compareTo(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Object
    System.out.println(proxy.compareTo("hoppu"));
                            ^
1 error
```

I also tried with Integer ...same error.

Comment: You've called your class `proxy` rather than `Proxy`, which is probably confusing things...

Comment: In your `main` method, what is `i` (the arg to `new Handler(i)`)?

Answer (score 3):

You created your proxy object, but you didn't cast it to `Comparable` before calling `compareTo`.  As an `Object`, the Java compiler doesn't know that `proxy` is anything but an `Object`.

The proxy returned must be cast to an interface that is supported by the object, not the actual class of the original object, according to the [javadocs for Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

```
Comparable c = (Comparable) Proxy.newProxyInstance(null,interfaces,handler);
System.out.println(c.compareTo("hoppu"));
```

Additionally, as pointed out by others, calling your class `proxy` and a variable `proxy` can be confusing.  Conventionally, class names are capitalized, e.g. "Proxy", or even better, "MyProxy" here to avoid name collision with the built-in Java `Proxy` class.

Comment: proxy.java:26: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type java.lang.Comparable
 System.out.println(c.compareTo("hopp"));
                               ^
1 warning

Comment: @AdityaKumar - I don't think there's a way of avoiding the warning; you'll have to suppress it. (BTW, I'm honored that you are now comparing the proxy to me. :) )

Comment: I am able to run it through casting it to Comparable..but it throws exception after the compareTo code... it throws java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Comment: You will need to examine the Exception contained in the UndeclaredThrowableException to determine the cause.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the returned `proxy` to `String`, because `Object` don't really have a `compareTo(String)`.

**EDIT**

As I forgot, you will only be able to cast the created proxy to an interface. You could use @rgettman sollution.

Comment: Also, check the comment from Oli Charlesworth, it might come in handy for OP

Comment: It thorws thisException in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at proxy.main(proxy.java:23)

Comment: I don't think casting to a `String` will work. The returned object is not a `String` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy object has no `compareTo` method on it.  Even if it does dynamically implement that interface from `String`, you cannot invoke that method without casting it to the appropriate interface (in this case, `Comparable`).